# Why use google oauath isSignedIn,listen()?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, oauth-2.0, google-oauth

`GoogleAuth.isSignedIn.listen(listener)`
Listen for changes in the current user's sign-in state.
What does it do?

Comment: Without wanting to sound patronising, it listens for a change in the current users state (https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/reference). This allows you to execute a function when the state changes.
It might make more sense if you elaborate on the context you're using it in, what you're trying to achieve, and what problem(s) you're facing. As at the minute it just sounds like you're asking for info around the method rather than help with a specific problem.

Comment: thanks i got it....